# NG0301: Export of name 'matMenu' not found

Tags: angular

My code compiles just fine however when I go to the browser to navigate to a next page I get the following error in the console : " Export of name 'matMenu' not found!"

I dont understand why because, I have the imports for it in my app.module.ts file and also in spec.ts file. Can someone please help me? Here are some code snippets. I am using Angular 13[both version and cli]

spec.ts

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatMenuModule],
      declarations: [ ViewUsersComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ViewUsersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

app.module.ts

```
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatMenuModule,
```

]

Comment: The error is in the template, either in the “ matMenuTriggerFor” or in the “<mat-menu” tag. Paste the code here to get further help please.

Comment: That is the thing, I am not using any mat-menu tag at all. I ended up finding the solution to the problem. It seems my angular project created a folder called .angular and inside it was a folder called cache which contained components that I had deleted. So I removed that folder from my angular project and it worked fine now

Comment: I have been looking for this solution all day. You should make this an answer and official solution. I figured it was a cache thing but didnt notice that folder.

Comment: Thank you @Luigi you saved my day ! Before having the .angular folder a script restart would do the trick but now we have to delete it. I'll add that top my clean script !

Comment: @ReneTrujillo Just did

Comment: @Elvynia , its nice to know my answer to a problem helped someone *cheers*

Answer (score 6):

Clearing the folder called .angular in your angular project can solve "matmenu" errors. Also , if you remove/delete a component from your project that you no longer need it can also cause this problem even after manually removing the associated imports from the app.module.ts file as well as the app.routing.ts file

Comment: Because I was using jest, I used jest --clearCache in combination with deleting .angular folder. This fixed issue for me.